# StoreFront api shopify in Flutter app ("Nodes" & "Edges" conflicting class names)

Tags: flutter, shopify, shopify-storefront-api

My need is very simple.

I want to query Shopify's Storefront api using Flutter, but there is a catch.

My response always have multiple nodes and edges. and each node/edge containing different objects.

Now the problem arise when i try to use JsonToDart generator in android studio and it creates each class with its own model. containing different fields and it conflicts with the other Node class.

screenshot is attached for reference.
i want to know how i can tackle this problem.

my graphQL query is:

```
{
  products(first: 2) {
    nodes {
      id
      title
  createdAt
  description
  descriptionHtml
  featuredImage {
    id
    url
    width
    height
    altText
  }
  onlineStoreUrl
  options {
    id
    name
    values
  }
  priceRange {
    maxVariantPrice {
      amount
      currencyCode
    }
    minVariantPrice {
      amount
      currencyCode
    }
  }
  productType
  publishedAt
  requiresSellingPlan
  seo {
    title
    description
  }
  tags
  totalInventory
  updatedAt
  vendor
  images(first: 2) {
    nodes {
      id
      url
      width
      height
      altText
    }
  }
  media(first: 2) {
    nodes {
      alt
      mediaContentType
    }
  }
  variants(first: 2) {
    nodes {
      availableForSale
      barcode
      id
      image {
        id
        url
        width
        height
        altText
      }
      requiresShipping
      sku
      title
      weight
      weightUnit
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have multiple classes called the same way, this creates confusion in your code, and if for any reason you do, they have to be defined in different files and whenever you import them somewhere you have to pick the right file to import it from